# Error "Invalid byte sequence for for encoding UTF-8: 0x00" in Pentaho from Mysql to Postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Anyone ever faced problems with NULL error UTF8 like in the picture ?
I'm doing just simple table input(mysql)=>select values=>table output(postgresql)
I thought with case when field is null then null will help, but it didn't, in the select values also i tried to force encoding UTF-8 but no luck...
Because there is so many data like this, and i can't fix it one by one, literally there are thousands of it
I'm inserting around 30millions of it

I'm also already "Enable Lazy Conversion"

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 0):

[The PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) tells you that

> Regardless of the specific character set, the character with code zero (sometimes called NUL) cannot be stored.

There is no way you can get that character into a PostgreSQL database. You will have to remove these characters from the strings during the ETL process.

Comment: Is there a way that i can know which field has that value? because there are like 38-40ish fields, and when i do select , can't seem to find which field has the fault

Comment: I don't know about MySQL, but perhaps something like `WHERE colname LIKE '%' || CHAR(0 using ASCII) || '%'`.

Comment: A simple way to remove it in this context, where MySQL is the input, is to replace it with something else on your input step query, with `select ..., replace(columnName, '\0', 'NUL') ...`